# ERROR: ResolutionImpossible when installing tensorflowjs_converter

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow.js

When I try to install `tensorflowjs_converter` to convert my `model.h5` to a json file it doesn't install it, I used `pip3 install tensorflowjs` to install it and it returns this error message:

> ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies

Here is what happened before the error appeared:

```
Collecting tensorflowjs
  Using cached tensorflowjs-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
Collecting h5py<3,>=2.8.0
  Using cached h5py-2.10.0.tar.gz (301 kB)
Collecting tensorflowjs
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.8.5-py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.8.4-py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.8.3-py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting h5py>=2.8.0
  Using cached h5py-3.1.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.7 MB)
Collecting PyInquirer==1.0.3
  Using cached PyInquirer-1.0.3.tar.gz (27 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-hub==0.7.0
  Using cached tensorflow_hub-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (89 kB)
Collecting numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.4
  Downloading numpy-1.18.5.zip (5.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.4 MB 930 kB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.12.0 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from tensorflowjs) (1.15.0)
Collecting tensorflowjs
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.0.1.post1-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.4 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from tensorflowjs) (1.19.5)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.7.4.post1-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.7.4-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting gast==0.2.2
  Using cached gast-0.2.2.tar.gz (10 kB)
Collecting tensorflowjs
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.7.3-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.2.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Collecting h5py==2.8.0
  Using cached h5py-2.8.0.tar.gz (274 kB)
Collecting tensorflowjs
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.2.10-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.2.9-py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
Collecting keras==2.2.4
  Using cached Keras-2.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (312 kB)
Collecting tensorflowjs
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.2.6-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-hub==0.3.0
  Using cached tensorflow_hub-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (73 kB)
Collecting tensorflowjs
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.15.1
  Using cached numpy-1.15.1.zip (4.5 MB)
Collecting tensorflowjs
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.8.6-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-hub==0.1.1
  Using cached tensorflow_hub-0.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
Collecting keras==2.2.2
  Using cached Keras-2.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (299 kB)
Collecting tensorflowjs
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.8.5-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.6.7-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.6.5-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Collecting six==1.11.0
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting tensorflowjs
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.6.4-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.5.7-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.14.1
  Using cached numpy-1.14.1.zip (4.9 MB)
Collecting tensorflowjs
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.5.6-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.5.4-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-hub==0.1.0
  Downloading tensorflow_hub-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 53 kB 3.8 MB/s
Collecting tensorflowjs
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Using cached tensorflowjs-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
ERROR: Cannot install tensorflowjs==0.1.0, tensorflowjs==0.1.1, tensorflowjs==0.1.2, tensorflowjs==0.2.0, tensorflowjs==0.2.1, tensorflowjs==0.3.0, tensorflowjs==0.3.1, tensorflowjs==0.4.0, tensorflowjs==0.4.1, tensorflowjs==0.4.2, tensorflowjs==0.5.0, tensorflowjs==0.5.2, tensorflowjs==0.5.4, tensorflowjs==0.5.6, tensorflowjs==0.5.7, tensorflowjs==0.6.0, tensorflowjs==0.6.1, tensorflowjs==0.6.2, tensorflowjs==0.6.4, tensorflowjs==0.6.5, tensorflowjs==0.6.7, tensorflowjs==0.8.0, tensorflowjs==0.8.5, tensorflowjs==0.8.6, tensorflowjs==1.0.1, tensorflowjs==1.1.2, tensorflowjs==1.2.1, tensorflowjs==1.2.10, tensorflowjs==1.2.10.1, tensorflowjs==1.2.2, tensorflowjs==1.2.2.1, tensorflowjs==1.2.3, tensorflowjs==1.2.6, tensorflowjs==1.2.9, tensorflowjs==1.3.1, tensorflowjs==1.3.1.1, tensorflowjs==1.3.2, tensorflowjs==1.4.0, tensorflowjs==1.5.2, tensorflowjs==1.6.0, tensorflowjs==1.7.2, tensorflowjs==1.7.3, tensorflowjs==1.7.4, tensorflowjs==1.7.4.post1, tensorflowjs==2.0.0, tensorflowjs==2.0.1, tensorflowjs==2.0.1.post1, tensorflowjs==2.1.0, tensorflowjs==2.3.0, tensorflowjs==2.4.0, tensorflowjs==2.5.0, tensorflowjs==2.6.0, tensorflowjs==2.7.0, tensorflowjs==2.8.0, tensorflowjs==2.8.1, tensorflowjs==2.8.2, tensorflowjs==2.8.3, tensorflowjs==2.8.4, tensorflowjs==2.8.5 and tensorflowjs==3.0.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    tensorflowjs 3.0.0 depends on tensorflow<3 and >=2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 2.8.5 depends on tensorflow<3 and >=2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 2.8.4 depends on tensorflow<3 and >=2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 2.8.3 depends on tensorflow<3 and >=2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 2.8.2 depends on tensorflow<3 and >=2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 2.8.1 depends on tensorflow<3 and >=2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 2.8.0 depends on tensorflow<3 and >=2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 2.7.0 depends on tensorflow<3 and >=2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 2.6.0 depends on tensorflow<3 and >=2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 2.5.0 depends on tensorflow<3 and >=2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 2.4.0 depends on tensorflow-cpu<3 and >=2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 2.3.0 depends on tensorflow-cpu<3 and >=2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 2.1.0 depends on tensorflow-cpu<3 and >=2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 2.0.1.post1 depends on tensorflow-cpu<3 and >=2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 2.0.1 depends on tensorflow-cpu>=2.1.0<3
    tensorflowjs 2.0.0 depends on tensorflow-cpu>=2.1.0<3
    tensorflowjs 1.7.4.post1 depends on tensorflow-cpu>=2.1.0<3
    tensorflowjs 1.7.4 depends on tensorflow-cpu==2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 1.7.3 depends on tensorflow-cpu==2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 1.7.2 depends on tensorflow-cpu==2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 1.6.0 depends on tensorflow-cpu==2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 1.5.2 depends on tensorflow-cpu==2.1.0
    tensorflowjs 1.4.0 depends on tensorflow==1.15.0
    tensorflowjs 1.3.2 depends on tensorflow==1.15.0
    tensorflowjs 1.3.1.1 depends on tensorflow==1.15.0
    tensorflowjs 1.3.1 depends on tensorflow==1.15.0
    tensorflowjs 1.2.10.1 depends on tensorflow==1.14.0
    tensorflowjs 1.2.10 depends on tensorflow==1.14.0
    tensorflowjs 1.2.9 depends on tensorflow==1.14.0
    tensorflowjs 1.2.6 depends on tensorflow==1.14.0
    tensorflowjs 1.2.3 depends on tensorflow==1.14.0
    tensorflowjs 1.2.2.1 depends on tensorflow==1.14.0
    tensorflowjs 1.2.2 depends on tensorflow==1.14.0
    tensorflowjs 1.2.1 depends on tf-nightly-2.0-preview==2.0.0.dev20190605
    tensorflowjs 1.1.2 depends on tf-nightly-2.0-preview>=2.0.0.dev20190502
    tensorflowjs 1.0.1 depends on tf-nightly-2.0-preview>=2.0.0.dev20190304
    tensorflowjs 0.8.6 depends on tensorflow==1.13.1
    tensorflowjs 0.8.5 depends on tensorflow==1.13.1
    tensorflowjs 0.8.0 depends on tensorflow==1.12.0
    tensorflowjs 0.6.7 depends on tensorflow==1.12.0
    tensorflowjs 0.6.5 depends on tensorflow==1.11.0
    tensorflowjs 0.6.4 depends on tensorflow==1.11.0
    tensorflowjs 0.6.2 depends on tensorflow==1.11.0
    tensorflowjs 0.6.1 depends on tensorflow==1.10.1
    tensorflowjs 0.6.0 depends on tensorflow==1.10.1
    tensorflowjs 0.5.7 depends on tensorflow==1.9.0
    tensorflowjs 0.5.6 depends on tensorflow==1.9.0
    tensorflowjs 0.5.4 depends on tensorflow==1.9.0
    tensorflowjs 0.5.2 depends on tensorflow==1.8.0
    tensorflowjs 0.5.0 depends on tensorflow==1.8.0
    tensorflowjs 0.4.2 depends on tensorflow==1.8.0
    tensorflowjs 0.4.1 depends on tensorflow==1.8.0
    tensorflowjs 0.4.0 depends on tensorflow==1.7.0
    tensorflowjs 0.3.1 depends on tensorflow==1.7.0
    tensorflowjs 0.3.0 depends on tensorflow==1.7.0
    tensorflowjs 0.2.1 depends on tensorflow==1.7.0
    tensorflowjs 0.2.0 depends on tensorflow==1.7.0
    tensorflowjs 0.1.2 depends on tensorflow==1.7.0
    tensorflowjs 0.1.1 depends on tensorflow>=1.6.0
    tensorflowjs 0.1.0 depends on tensorflow>=1.6.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

I tried using `pip` but same results, if I didn't provide enough information, please comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tensorflowjs` requires `tensorflow` and  `tensorflow` [currently (at veriosn 2.4.1)](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.4.1/#files) doesn't support Python 3.9. Only 64-bit Python 3.6-3.8 are supported.

Downgrade to Python 3.8.

Comment: I am already using python 3.8.6 and It doesn't work.
EDIT: the message in the question was actually using 3.9 but I delete it from my machine and installed 3.8.6 and it returns same conflict issue

Comment: @Ahmadfromjameedium I'd like to see the new error with Python 3.8.

Comment: well your suggestion is right into the point the problem I was having is just a big mess in python versions installed all over the place.

Comment: I just uninstalled every thing and hunted every version and installed a clean 3.8.6 installation. thanks a lot @phd.